# Check if an epoch timestamp is within a given human readable time range in c++

Tags: c++, epoch

I have a

```
uint64_t ts=1523613515992249788
std::string t1; std::string t2; //example t1="09:00",t2="15:30"
```

t1 and t2 are given by user, and stored by my code as `std::string` (this is human readable time in HH:MM format)

The above ts is

- GMT: Friday, 13 April 2018 09:58:35.992
- IST: Friday, 13 April 2018 15:28:35.992 GMT+05:30

by default i assume t1 and t2 are in IST , ( given as command line argument)
I am trying to write a function like below

```
bool isTSinRange(uint64_t ts) {
// how to make t1 t2 ts comparable and do the below
 if (t1<ts<t2)
  return true;
 else 
  return false; }
```

Using gcc 4.8.3 and cannot use boost library

Full code: https://pastebin.com/bCpkQyFM

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you have. Is it with the parsing of the "human readable" values? In the comparison itself? Something else? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you read [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: yes i fixed the title for more clarity

Comment: @pythonRcpp still you haven't mentioned your problem. What are the error msgs you are getting or what exactly is your qestion?

Comment: i just want to compare `t1 t2 ts` , in the `isTSinRange` function, `t1 t2` is string, `ts` is `uint64_t`

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: You can not directly compare a uint64_t to a string, you must convert one type or the other.  Comparisons do not concatenate that way ... with int a, b, c; you can do ((a < b) && (b < c)), but not a < b < c.  (Well, software is infinitely flexible, so with motivation you might overload the operators.)

Comment: gcc-4.8.3 is a 4 year old compiler at this point.  If you are willing to upgrade your compiler, and use a 3rd party library, this problem is very easily solved by [an existing implementation of a C++20 std::lib](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html). The solution is about 16 lines of easily readable code.

Comment: and what structure should have an "epoch timestamp" ? Did you mean an Unix Timestamp ?

Comment: where is it defined ?

Comment: yes unix epoch timestamp